# Some of the Camel IN exchange Headers are not mapped to HTTP headers although both mapHttpMessageHeaders and copyHeaders are default true

Tags: http, http-headers, apache-camel

I am using Camel version 3.1.0 and its http component for calling a REST endpoint which requires headers like: date, host, digest, authorization, etc. for security. However when I set all these headers in the route before sending request to the http component, the "date" HTTP header is always missing. Tested with both WireMock and the real test environment. Also wield is that the test passes if I run it together with several other tests but not individually.

Here is the code:

```
        .setHeader("flowId", simple("\${body.flowId}"))
        .process { exchange ->
            with(pubsubConfig) { exchange.setPubsubTimeHeaders(minIntervalValueMills, maxIntervalValueMills, timeoutMillis) }

            val settlementAdviceRequestDto = exchange.message.body as SettlementAdviceRequestDto
            exchange.setProperty("settlementAdviceRequestDto", settlementAdviceRequestDto)

            // Setting security headers
            request.entity = StringEntity(jacksonObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(settlementAdviceRequestDto))
            signer.signRequest(request, exchange.message)
        }
        .marshal(settlementAdviceRequestJacksonDataFormat)
        .logInfoWithBreadCrumbId("Received SettlementAdviceRequestDto from PubSub, flowId: \${header.flowId}, sending to N&TS with \${headers}")
        .to(with(ntsConfigProperties) {
            "$protocol://$host:$port/$path?" +
                    "httpClient.maxConnTotal=$maxConnectionsTotal" +
                    "&httpClient.maxConnPerRoute=$maxConnectionsPerRoute" +
                    "&httpClient.connectionRequestTimeout=$connectionRequestTimeout" +
                    "&httpClient.connectTimeout=$connectionTimeout" +
                    "&httpClient.socketTimeout=$socketTimeout" +
                    "&httpClient.redirectsEnabled=$followRedirects"
        })
        .logInfoWithBreadCrumbId("SettlementAdviceRequestDto sent to N&TS, flowId: \${header.flowId} \${headers}")
```

Here is the logs from the test with checking the date header:

2020-05-13 11:11:22.267  INFO 5514 --- [tlement.advice]] o.c.f.f.s.route.SettlementAdviceRoute    : [ID-C02VC27UHTD6-liping-1589361082160-0-1] Received SettlementAdviceRequestDto from PubSub, flowId: 550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000, sending to N&TS with {CamelGooglePubsub.MsgAckId=TgQhIT4wPkVTRFAGFixdRkhRNxkIaFEOT14jPzUgKEUQC1MTUVx2B0YQajNcdQdRDRh1f2Ehbg4UBQEXWX5VWwk8aH58dAZUDRt2eGJ1aF8bCANCW1a0tP24kajpRx1tNZCxo6RASsXWuO52Zhg9XBJLLD5-KTBFQV5AEkwiBURJUytDCypYEQ, CamelGooglePubsub.MessageId=1150245302589178, CamelGooglePubsub.PublishTime=2020-05-13T09:11:20.194Z, breadcrumbId=ID-C02VC27UHTD6-liping-1589361082160-0-1, flowId=550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000, CamelGooglePubsub.AckDeadline=2, CamelPubsubHeader.Lifetime=2047, CamelPubsubHeader.LifeTimeout=5000, date=Wed, 13 May 2020 09:11:22 GMT, host=localhost, content-type=application/json, content-length=417, digest=SHA-256=Ocdp4q+ZLUshftQIsycfkidD2SEEnvU29TpX/AFkMt4=, Authorization= keyId="id",algorithm="hmac-sha256",headers="date (request-target) host content-length content-type digest",signature="j/GUbOD0UijQJEjuwCrehQ+seoJ9yeHObYGXbuZgJJY="}

2020-05-13 11:11:22.328  INFO 5514 --- [tp293974199-118] /                                        : RequestHandlerClass from context returned com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.StubRequestHandler. Normalized mapped under returned 'null'

2020-05-13 11:11:22.373 ERROR 5514 --- [tp293974199-118] WireMock                               :

```
                                Request was not matched
                                =======================
date [contains] : GMT                      |                  <<<<< Header is not present
host [contains] : localhost                | host: localhost:14685
content-length [contains] : 417            | content-length: 417
content-type [contains] : application/json | content-type: application/json
digest [contains] :                        | digest:
...
```

Here is logs from the test without checking the date header:

2020-05-13 11:20:09.092  INFO 5628 --- [tlement.advice]] o.c.f.f.s.route.SettlementAdviceRoute    : [ID-C02VC27UHTD6-liping-1589361608990-0-1] Received SettlementAdviceRequestDto from PubSub, flowId: 550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000, sending to N&TS with {CamelGooglePubsub.MsgAckId=BCEhPjA-RVNEUAYWLF1GSFE3GQhoUQ5PXiM_NSAoRRIGCBQFfH1yR1B1XjN1B1ENGXN6Y3U-XxYGVEUCdF9RGx9ZXH5VBlAIGXB-ZnZvWxoFA0BTeXfQ16DUpajANUsxIYq6v7BfeuyjqYNhZhs9XxJLLD5-KStFQV5AEkwiHkRJUytDCypYEU4, CamelGooglePubsub.MessageId=1150237351941507, CamelGooglePubsub.PublishTime=2020-05-13T09:20:07.119Z, breadcrumbId=ID-C02VC27UHTD6-liping-1589361608990-0-1, flowId=550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000, CamelGooglePubsub.AckDeadline=1, CamelPubsubHeader.Lifetime=1949, CamelPubsubHeader.LifeTimeout=5000, date=Wed, 13 May 2020 09:20:09 GMT, host=localhost, content-type=application/json, content-length=417, digest=SHA-256=Ocdp4q+ZLUshftQIsycfkidD2SEEnvU29TpX/AFkMt4=, Authorization= keyId="id",algorithm="hmac-sha256",headers="date (request-target) host content-length content-type digest",signature="POpggmhIDI8tNBsb7239ksYEGfwY+IB/Rn93PCrkGsY="}

2020-05-13 11:20:09.145  INFO 5628 --- [tp294593670-119] /                                        : RequestHandlerClass from context returned com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.StubRequestHandler. Normalized mapped under returned 'null'

2020-05-13 11:20:09.434  INFO 5628 --- [tlement.advice]] o.c.f.f.s.route.SettlementAdviceRoute    : [ID-C02VC27UHTD6-liping-1589361608990-0-1] SettlementAdviceRequestDto sent to N&TS, flowId: 550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000 {CamelHttpResponseCode=200, CamelHttpResponseText=OK, Matched-Stub-Id=4efce26c-dbfa-457e-864d-98f29ef38f97, Vary=Accept-Encoding, User-Agent, Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Server=Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT), CamelGooglePubsub.MsgAckId=BCEhPjA-RVNEUAYWLF1GSFE3GQhoUQ5PXiM_NSAoRRIGCBQFfH1yR1B1XjN1B1ENGXN6Y3U-XxYGVEUCdF9RGx9ZXH5VBlAIGXB-ZnZvWxoFA0BTeXfQ16DUpajANUsxIYq6v7BfeuyjqYNhZhs9XxJLLD5-KStFQV5AEkwiHkRJUytDCypYEU4, CamelGooglePubsub.MessageId=1150237351941507, CamelGooglePubsub.PublishTime=2020-05-13T09:20:07.119Z, breadcrumbId=ID-C02VC27UHTD6-liping-1589361608990-0-1, flowId=550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000, CamelGooglePubsub.AckDeadline=1, CamelPubsubHeader.Lifetime=1949, CamelPubsubHeader.LifeTimeout=5000, digest=SHA-256=Ocdp4q+ZLUshftQIsycfkidD2SEEnvU29TpX/AFkMt4=, Authorization= keyId="id",algorithm="hmac-sha256",headers="date (request-target) host content-length content-type digest",signature="POpggmhIDI8tNBsb7239ksYEGfwY+IB/Rn93PCrkGsY="}